# QGIS Count lines in polygon ( to be part of a graphical model )

Tags: qgis, polygon, geoprocessing, line, qgis-modeler

My problem is very easy to understand but I can't find a solution.

I'm actually working on the spreading of a local optic fibre network. These fibres will be contained in plastic tubes buried in trenches. I need to know how many tubes we should bury in each trench.

In GIS words : I make a buffer from the polyline shapefile "trenches", and I need to know how many polylines from the "tubes" shapefile cross (all the lines starts and ends out of the buffers) this buffer, then create a new shapefile with a column containing this count.

I though that there was a geoprocessing tool which could do it just like the "count points in polygon" geoprocessing tool. But it doesn't exist in QGIS Version 2.14.13.

So, I'm looking for a similar method that could be integrated in a graphical modeller, as a one-click operation (because I'll have to do it several times, and so will do my colleagues).

Comment: Could you upload an image that explain graphically the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the **Join attributes by location** tool (which hopefully should in available in your modeler). If you select the *Attribute summary* option and choose `Take summary of intersecting features`, it will insert a `Count` field into your layer. If you don't want to calculate the `sum, mean` etc then just remove them so that the textbox is blank, that way you will only get the `Count` field as the statistic:

[image: Join attributes by location]

Comment: Of course ! I was searching for very complex methods since days but just forgot the easiest...Thanks a lot, Joseph !

Comment: @Drawfib38 - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Comment: To obtain these options in QGIS 3, one has to use the tool "Join attributes by location (summary)"